# Why position of an object is unique?

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics

Position in physics is defined as the location of an object w.r.t some reference point.
I conceptualized it as the description of the path from the reference point to the location of the object. My question is as there are multiple paths from the reference point to the object location than why the position of the object is unique w.r.t the reference point.

[image: image of a position of an object]

In the image shown above, we can reach the red point via multiple paths in fact there is an infinite number of paths than why the location of an object is unique w.r.t a reference point.

Comment: The word "location" doesn't specify how an object arrived at that point. There is an infinite number of ways to move an object from the origin to any point in your diagram but that object always ends up at a single, unique location relative to the origin.

Comment: Charlie thanks for your response.A point is located in-plane and its position is (3,4). Then that position also specify how to reach from origin to that point

Comment: The coordinates don't contain any information about any particular *path* between the origin and that point. What happens if I have a surface that is in $>1$ pieces (i.e. it is disconnected and broken up into several separate pieces) and I label each of the points with coordinates? Nothing stops me from simply labelling the points even though there now exists *no* possible continuous path between some of the points. Is that a helpful counterexample?

Comment: Charlie, I still can't get your point. I think I am the dumbest of all human being.

Comment: If locations *weren't* unique, the notion of defining a path wouldn't make much sense, as a path is just a series of locations. The situation would be considerably worse than there being an infinite number of paths between points - there would be an arbitrary number of ways to describe an *individual, fixed* path.

Comment: Charlie can you simply explain your counter example

Comment: @Muslim Maybe you're getting confused because we usually label the points with numbers like (4,3) and that's giving you the impression that the coordinates are somehow "telling" you to travel 4 units in one direction and 3 units in another from the origin? If so, remember that you can label the points *however* you want, you could label the points with colours or letters or random symbols if you wanted to (although you might find this less useful if you're intending to do mathematical calculations). Is that closer to what's bothering you?

Comment: @Charlie Yes you are right charlie but the colour doesn't tell about location and numbers does

Comment: To elaborate slightly on what I said before. Imagine taking the flat plane you've drawn in your question and breaking it into two pieces. You can still label the points in the exact same way since that's all the coordinates are, just a label for each of the points so you can tell them apart in some way. However, now that the plane is in two pieces you can't drawn a continuous line between all of the points because some of the points are on different pieces of the surface. Notice that this hasn't stopped you from keeping your coordinates and now you can't drawn *any* paths between some points.

Comment: @Muslim Sure, labelling the points with colours rather than numbers is less helpful for doing mathematical calculations, but the principle is exactly the same, you're just labelling the points so you can tell them apart in some way. Maybe consider this, if I tell you to go to "Paris", you know exactly where that is and how to get there even though I've given you a word and not a series of GPS coordinates. Both the word "Paris" and whatever the GPS coordinates of Paris are label a specific place on Earth, but neither tells you about the path between you and Paris.

Comment: @Charlie now I understand the position. Many many thanks God bless you

Comment: Glad it helped, good luck :)

Comment: @Charlie I have another question? If the position is just a label for the point that why we use a vector to specify it as position does not have magnitude and direction. Explain it in as simple terms as possible. Thanks for your precious time and sorry for disturbing you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120448/discussion-between-muslim-and-charlie).

Answer (score 6):

You say that  *"I conceptualized it as the description of the path from the reference point to the location of the object"* and you found that led to a nonsensical answer. Therefore your concept is flawed.

The location is the endpoint of the path, not the path itself. Indeed, it is the endpoint of infinitely many alternative paths.

In quantum physics these alternative paths can traverse time as well as space!

But in classical physics, just the straight path from the origin may be taken, and the point treated as the associated [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)). The point is then unique, as you conceived. Space as a whole may then be treated mathematically as a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field), which is to say that it is not just a set of point locations any more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding upon Charlie's comment, which is correct. The position is defined by a set of numbers, called coordinates, and not by any of the infinite possible ways to connect that point to the origin. In cartesian coordinates, those numbers are the position of the $x$-axis and on the $y$-axis so for example a point could be in the position (1,3) by which it is meant $x=1$ and $y=3$. *Those numbers* are w.r.t. the reference point, the origin, which has, by definition, coordinates (0,0).

Comment: Coordinates also tell us how to reach from origin to that point. For example, A point has a position  (2,3) means you have to go 2 unit on the x-axis and 3 unit on the y-axis. Thanks for your response.

Comment: No, they don't. How could they? There are infinite ways to reach a point from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Position is about location in space, not the path you took to get there. If we do not know how an object ended up where it is we can still agree on where it is. Hence the path does not matter.

The thing that can relate to path is coordinates. We want to denote a position with some  set of numbers that ideally are unique. This can be done by defining a chart, a function that maps some neighbourhood of the reference point and the point we care about to normal flat space, and then "pull back" coordinates that work in the environment we actually think about. It turns out that if you can always do this, then your environment is a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold). But sometimes the charts can only be local, and you need to patch them together chart by chart to reach your point. On some manifolds that mean you can reach it in different ways, and these ways give rise to different coordinates for the point. But this is a disagreement about how to label it, not what point it is.